# msync guarantees on linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, mmap

Is `msync` guaranteed to physically write dates into the hard-drive? Can I be 100% sure that if the OS crashes immediately after `msync` returns, that I won't lose data?

By 100% sure I mean that the data was physically written to the disk and not just hard drive buffer. Simply, I want to be sure that losing electricity won't result in loss of data.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145698/what-does-the-barrier-mount-flag-mean-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible for data to be lost if the OS crashes after msync returns. Its because the data may still be stored in the file system cache and not yet written to the storage device. To guarantee that data is not lost in the event of an OS crash, you can use the `fsync` system call to synchronize the file system cache with the storage device. To be extra sure you should use a disk journaling filesystem like ext3, ext4, jfs, ntfs, reiserfs, xfs etc, that ensure that the filesystem remains consistent in case of a crash or power failure.

Comment: I always thought that `msync` does the same stuff as `fsync`, just for memory mapped files. Are you saying that is not the case? Do you have more supporting info for that?

Comment: It does the same stuff basicly, while `msync` ensures that any changes made to the memory-mapped region are written to the storage device. `fsync`  ensures that any changes made to the file or directory are written to the storage device INCLUDING changes made to the file system's in-memory data structures. And that is useful if you want to ensure that changes to a file is durable in the eevent of a system crash etc. As a source you can look up man7.org/linux/. For both fsync and msync.

Comment: I am bit confused about the INCLUDING part. You just said that changes made to memory mapped region are written to storage device with msync. So, why do I need to call fsync too? Can you give me an example of the failure mode of msync? I.e. what could go wrong if I call only msync and not fsync?